# Does the split function in Processing and in Eclipse exist in actual Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

Does the .split() function even exist?
When I type:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numbers = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
        int[] numbers2 = (int[]) numbers.split(", ");
    
        System.out.println(numbers2);
    }
}
```

It says:

```
Main.java:4: error: incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to int[]
    int[] numbers2 = (int[]) numbers.split(", ");
                                          ^
1 error
```

Comment: Yes it exists. And your error isn't about that.

Comment: `split` returns an array of Strings, you can't just cast that to an array of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes the method **String[] split​(String regex)** for reference type String exists, here is the reference https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) for **Java SE 11**.

But you are trying to **cast** a variable of reference type **String** to an array of primitive **int**-type, which cannot be achieved directly in Java without **parsing**.

1. Split your String variable into a String-Array

   ```
   String numbers = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
   String[] numbersSplitted = numbers.split(", ");
   ```
2. Parse your String-Array to an int-Array

   ```
   int [] numbersParsed = new int[numbersSplitted.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < numbersSplitted.length; i++){
       numbersParsed[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersSplitted[i]);
   }
   ```
3. Print the parsed array or each element of the parsed array out to the console

   `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersParsed));`

   ```
    // or print each element of the parsed array

    for (int val : numbersParsed) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
   ```

Hopefully, this will help out!

Answer (score 5):

[`numbers.split(", ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) returns a `String` array. You can use the following to map a `String` array to an `int` array.

```
int[] numbers2 = Arrays.stream(numbers.split(", ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Using Pattern.splitAsStream would avoid creating the intermediate string array. `Pattern.compile(", *").splitAsStream(numbers).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: note the spaces in the input. Better would be `split("\\s*,\\s*")` or the method trim somewhere in there

Comment: @greg-449 I have benchmarked it, and creating a new array is way faster than `Pattern.compile()` even when the pattern is a constant

Comment: @YassinHajaj I didn't say faster, I said avoids the intermediate array. Did you use a proper benchmark tool? Pattern.compile is useful because you can make it a `static` that is only compiled once. `splitAsStream` is most useful when the stream has short-circuiting operations which mean part of the split does not have to be done.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes I used JMH with and without a static pattern, both slower